# When updating library/list description it adds links to the left/structured navigation

Tags: current-navigation, sharepoint-standard, left-navigation

I already set left navigation manually.
When i try to update library/list descriptions it adds link in the left navigation dynamically.

**Note:** For Some of the library/list only it is happening.

Is there any way to resolve this. Why it is happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding link to the structured navigation manually is the issue.
I resolved to delete all manually created links and use the default link which is created when we do the below steps,
List Settings->List name,description-> Select Display in the Quick launch

Answer (score 0):

If its specific site collection why don't go to site settings >> navigation settings and remove the "Recent" heading and its links.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shaikh. I tried. My issue is different. The newly created duplicate link is not showing inside Recent Folder.